# Are there any fundamental constraints for using JS in browsers?

Tags: javascript, http, browser

Why don't browsers incorporate any other language than JavaScript as a scripting language. Is there any **fundamental reason** that prevents them from allowing some other language such as Python, or any other language for scripting. Has there been any effort in this direction  which didn't succeed or is it the case that since javaScript served its purpose so well that nobody thought of any alternative ?

Comment: Coalescing around a single language/approach for scripting to normalize *all web browsers in the world* with is much easier than doing the same for 2, or 3, or more scripting languages. Sure, browsers *could* also implement, eg, Python, but it'd be an extraordinarily huge effort for no gain, since the general scripting capabilities of JS are sufficient for browser tasks

Comment: @CertainPerformance "huge effort for no gain" I would argue against that since there might be "little" gain and over time who knows there might be huge gain. Not having alternative simply admits to the fact  that JS is perfect which is certainly not true.

Comment: Splitting front-end programmers among 2 utterly different language would be quite a loss. It's not that JS is perfect, but that *fundamentally* both it and Python have (or could potentially have) the same capabilities with regards to general scripting. Why have 2 radically different ecosystems (and all the confusion that comes with it) to accomplish the same thing when you can have one?

Comment: @CertainPerformance your argument can be made for dozens of situations where choice currently exist. Why have more than 1 operating system, 1 systems language? 1 editor? Yes there are advantages to having no choice, but there are also drawbacks.

Comment: So if everyone in the world ran Linux, it would definitely be easier to make applications that run everywhere. Some people would consider the lack of competition a loss though. Your flaw in thinking is that you look at the world through a lens where there is no choice, and assume it's the best world. Competition itself drives innovation. I remember a time though where many people felt Java was the last language anyone would ever need.

Comment: Funny, not more than 2 days ago [a new issue in HTML specs asked for something related.](https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/6460) But the whole Web APIs are built with a js environment for scripting in mind. Changing this would mean having to rewrite all the specs to work with an other language... We already have enough issues to fix with a single base. Also, one big advantage of JS over other languages is that its development is very active, and some of its developers also help to write the Web standards.

Comment: @Kaiido "But the whole Web APIs are built with a js environment for scripting in mind." So can it be otherwise , meaning can there be a  language that is invented to fit in that environment.

Comment: @Kaiido nice resource there. The thread has been closed though. There is a project called brython which attempts to bring the python syntax to browsers but underlying is the same old javascript. I guess whatever the BIG tech wants that is only acceptable. So much for freedom.

Comment: @Kaiido for what it's worth, I don't think we'll ever get a second language like JS, but with webassembly that might not matter.

Answer (score 1):

No, and other languages have been part of the browser runtime:

- VBScript / JScript
- Arguably: Actionscript, Java (via applets), Whatever Microsoft's answer was to Flash (silverlight?)
- Webassembly (getting more popular today, and can be a target for pretty much any other language.

I also distinctly remember an experiment on a Mozilla browser from years ago that actually brought `text/python` support. My google is failing me though, but this would have been at least 10 years ago and never made it in a stable release.

Comment: There is also [GLSL](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Core_Language_(GLSL)) However the truth is that Web APIs are built to work in a javascript environment.

Answer (score -1):

JavaScript is the most browser-friendly language because it has functions like `document._______` which scans the webpage. Not many other coding languages have that kind of function. Hope that answered your question.